# Match vectors on subset of digits in each element

Tags: r, match, digits

I am trying to see whether the elements in vector match with the first four digits of elements within a second vector (they are nested identifiers) and I'm not quite sure how to run the match. For example:

```
X     Y 
1111  111120
1111  890933
2222  780777
2222  222247
```

I would like to create code to tell me whether the first four digits of element i in vector y match the digits in element i in vector x. Extending the example, I hope to see:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apply` to loop over the rows and use `grepl` will work...

```
apply( df , 1 , function(x) grepl( x[1] , x[2] ) )
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: To match the first four digits, perhaps `grepl(paste0("^",x[1]),x[2])`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your data.frame is `df` and using `substr` will do the trick.

```
> df$X==as.numeric(substr(df$Y, start=1, stop=4))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Putting all together in a new data.frame:

```
> transform(df, Z=df$X==as.numeric(substr(df$Y, start=1, stop=4)))
     X      Y     Z
1 1111 111120  TRUE
2 1111 890933 FALSE
3 2222 780777 FALSE
4 2222 222247  TRUE
```

Take a look at `?substr` for further details on how it works.